# Perfect Swift3 Boing

Tags: ios, core-animation, game-physics

To animate a bar opening...

```
@IBOutlet var barHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!


    barHeight.constant = barShut?30:100
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    t = !barShut?30:100

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15,
        delay: 0,
        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut,

        animations: { () -> Void in
            self.barHeight.constant = t
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        },

        completion: {_ in
            Screen.barShut = !Screen.barShut
        }
    )
```

That's great ...

[image]

But how would you make it boing like this?

[image]

(The only way I'd know to do this is, use CADisplayLink, with a few lines of code for a spring decaying.) Is this available in UIKit?

Comment: Wouldn't you just use [animate​With​Duration:​delay:​using​Spring​With​Damping:​initial​Spring​Velocity:​options:​animations:​completion:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622594-animatewithduration) ?

Comment: You animate it just like you animate any other change to a constraint's `constant` - see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [spring animation method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622594-animatewithduration) that is built in to UIView:

```
func toggleBar() -> Void {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    let newHeight:CGFloat = !barShut ? 30:100
    barShut = !barShut

    barHeightConstraint.constant = newHeight

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2, initialSpringVelocity: 3, options: [], animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)

}
```

You will want a longer animation duration than 0.15 of a second in order for the bounce to seem realistic;  I think the values I have look pretty good, but you can play with them to get the exact effect you are after.

Since the animation duration is longer, I found that I could tap the button the triggered the open/shut while the previous animation was still running.  Setting `barShut` in the completion block meant that the bar didn't react to all taps. I moved the toggle outside of the animation to address this.

Comment: oh fantastic, the spring animation is built in !

Comment: just BTW for anyone reading, the handy `.beginFromCurrentState` can sometimes help in relation to the problem Paul mentions in the final para.